# Can scrapy setting custom variable in settings?

Tags: python, django, scrapy

I want to set a variable `ENV` in `settings.py`  like:

```
import sys, os
path_django_site = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "../../")  
sys.path.append(path_django_site)
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'pjt1.settings.dev'  
ENV = os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE']
```

So that in my spider project,I can write code like this:

```
if ENV =='pjt1.settings.dev':
    obj = Group.objects.filter(id__lte=10)
    print 'this is test'

elif ENV =='pjt.settings.prod':
    obj = Group.objects.all()
    print 'This is normal environvent'
```

is it posible?
Please guide me.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand the actual question, but you can set any variable in your settings.py and use it like this:

```
# your wsgi file probably includes something like this
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "pjt1.settings.dev")

# settings.py
ENV = os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE']

# other files
from django.conf import settings
if settings.ENV == 'pjt1.settings.dev':
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you so much. What I mean is : set ````ENV = os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE']```` in ````scrapy_project/settings.py````  ,and then I can called ````ENV```` in spiders to decide which environment to use